Deducing the conclusion from the premises using rules of inference or laws of logic
Show that the following argument is valid by deducing the conclusion from the premises step by step through the use of the basic rules of inference or laws of logic. Your answer should include the rule of inference or law of logic to justify your deductions.

$( p \lor \neg q ) \rightarrow \neg r$
$ \neg s \lor q$
$t$
$t \rightarrow p$
$( p \land \neg r ) \rightarrow s$

therefore $q$
Here's what I tried, I'm not sure if I am correct. Any help would be appreciated!
t → p
t
∴ p [modus ponens]
( p v ¬q ) → ¬r
p
∴ ¬r [disjunctive amplification]
p
¬r
∴ (p ∧ ¬r) [conjunction]
(p ∧ ¬r) → s
(p ∧ ¬r)
∴ s  [modus ponens]
¬s v q
s → q
s
∴ q  [modus ponens]

Your work seems correct
